# mongodb. merge array of objects to array of array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have collection with user actions like:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": "1",
        "action": "action_1",
        "timestamp": ISODate("2022-11-17T12:55:34.804+0000")
    },
    {
        "user_id": "1",
        "action": "action_2",
        "timestamp": ISODate("2022-11-17T14:55:34.804+0000")
    },
    {
        "user_id": "1",
        "action": "action_1",
        "timestamp": ISODate("2022-11-17T17:55:34.804+0000")
    },
    {
        "user_id": "1",
        "action": "action_1",
        "timestamp": ISODate("2022-11-18T11:55:34.804+0000")
    },
    {
        "user_id": "1",
        "action": "action_2",
        "timestamp": ISODate("2022-11-18T13:55:34.804+0000")
    },
    {
        "user_id": "1",
        "action": "action_2",
        "timestamp": ISODate("2022-11-18T15:55:34.804+0000")
    }
]
```

And collection with score of this actions:

```
[
    {
        "action": "action_1",
        "score": 1
    },
    {
        "action": "action_2",
        "score": 2
    }
]
```

I need give a single document with structure like:

```
{
    "res_date": [
        ["2022-11-17", 3, 5],
        # 1 array elem it is data from field date_actions.date
        # 2 array elem it is summ of all actions_count by this date
        # 3 array elem it is summ of all action_total_sc by this date
        ["2022-11-18", 3, 5]
    ],
    "act_stat": [
        {
            "action_name": "action_1",
            "actions_count": 3,
            "total_score": 3
        },
        {
            "action_name": "action_2",
            "actions_count": 3,
            "total_score": 6
        }
    ],
    "tot": {
        "ac": 6,
        "po": 9
    }
}
```

I write aggregation pipeline for grouping data from user_actions collection by action, getting score from second collection and finally merge data to one documents

```
[{
    $match: {
        'timestamp': {
            "$gte": ISODate('2022-11-17'),
            "$lt": ISODate('2022-11-23')
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "actions_score",
        localField: "action",
        foreignField: "action",
        as: "score"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$score"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                    date: {
                        $toDate: "$timestamp"
                    }
                }
            },
            action: "$action"
        },
        actions_count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        total_score: {
            $sum: "$score.score"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: "$_id.date",
            action: "$_id.action"
        },
        actions_count: {
            $sum: "$actions_count"
        },
        action_total_score: {
            $sum: "$total_score"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        res_date: {
            $push: {
                $arrayToObject: [
                    [{
                            k: "$_id.date",
                            v: "$actions_count"
                        },
                        {
                            k: "actions_count",
                            v: "$actions_count"
                        },
                        {
                            k: "action_total_score",
                            v: "$action_total_score"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        act_stat: {
            $push: {
                action_name: "$_id.action",
                actions_count: "$actions_count",
                total_score: "$action_total_score"
            }
        },
        tot: {
            $push: {
                ac: "$actions_count"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        res_date: 1,
        act_stat: 1,
        tot: {
            $arrayToObject: [
                [{
                    k: "ac",
                    v: {
                        $sum: "$tot.ac"
                    }
                }, {
                    k: "po",
                    v: {
                        $sum: "$act_stat.total_score"
                    }
                }]
            ]
        }
    }
}]
```

It pipeline give me almost expected result, but in res_date i have array of object instead array of array:

```
{
    "res_date": [
        {
            "2022-11-17": 3,
            "actions_count": 3,
            "action_total_score": 4
        },
        {
            "2022-11-21": 3,
            "actions_count": 3,
            "action_total_score": 5
        }
    ],
    "act_stat": [
        {
            "action_name": "action_1",
            "actions_count": 3,
            "total_score": 3
        },
        {
            "action_name": "action_2",
            "actions_count": 3,
            "total_score": 6
        }
    ],
    "tot": {
        "ac": 6,
        "po": 9
    }
}
```

How i can fix my pipeline for getting expected result?

Comment: In `"$group"`, you are `"$push"`'ing the objects.  Just `"$push"` an array of values that you want.

Comment: @rickhg12hs but how i can do it if push is unary operator? i can't do that   res_date: {
    $push: [
      [
        '$_id.date',"$actions_count","$action_total_score"]
      ]
  }

Comment: @rickhg12hs solve it with help of   res_date: {
        $push: {
          $concatArrays: [
            ['$_id.date', '$actions_count','$action_total_score']
          ]
        }
      } thanks for help )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved with help of $concatArrays. here is updated pipeline

```
[{
    $match: {
        'timestamp': {
            "$gte": ISODate('2022-11-17'),
            "$lt": ISODate('2022-11-23')
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "actions_score",
        localField: "action",
        foreignField: "action",
        as: "score"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$score"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                    date: {
                        $toDate: "$timestamp"
                    }
                }
            },
            action: "$action"
        },
        actions_count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        total_score: {
            $sum: "$score.score"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: "$_id.date",
            action: "$_id.action"
        },
        actions_count: {
            $sum: "$actions_count"
        },
        action_total_score: {
            $sum: "$total_score"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        res_date: {
            $push: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    ['$_id.date', '$actions_count', '$action_total_score']
                ]
            }
        },
        act_stat: {
            $push: {
                action_name: "$_id.action",
                actions_count: "$actions_count",
                total_score: "$action_total_score"
            }
        },
        tot: {
            $push: {
                ac: "$actions_count"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        res_date: 1,
        act_stat: 1,
        tot: {
            $arrayToObject: [
                [{
                    k: "ac",
                    v: {
                        $sum: "$tot.ac"
                    }
                }, {
                    k: "po",
                    v: {
                        $sum: "$act_stat.total_score"
                    }
                }]
            ]
        }
    }
}]
```